# groupby from Python's module itertools does not seem to group its input

Tags: python, python-itertools

I wanted to set a dictionary of even numbers using boolean keys and the groupby function from the itertools module.

The code seems to sort well by evens and not-evens but all the True and False keys should be grouped together inside the dictionary and they are not.

Code:

```py
# Set a dictionary of even numbers
from itertools import groupby
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def evens(arg):
  return arg%2==0

group_obj = groupby(ls, key=evens)

for key, value in group_obj:
  print(key, list(value))
```

Output:

```py
False [1]
True [2]
False [3]
True [4]
False [5]
True [6]
```

Expected output:

```py
False [1, 3, 5]
True [2, 4, 6]
```

Thank you on advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` does not sort the data.  You would need to sort it yourself, usually using the same `key`.  So this does exactly what you want:

```
group_obj = groupby(sorted(ls,key=evens), key=evens)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
False [1, 3, 5]
True [2, 4, 6]

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's starting a new group everytime if I don't sort them. Thank you very much!